# my object isn't being rendered

Tags: rendering

the door to my fridge isn't being rendered

this is it in modeling area

[image]

and this is it rendered

[image]

how do i get it to render the door

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the camera icon of your door object in Outliner. If it fades in like this then it won't be rendered.

[image]

You can turn it on with a click on this stuff.

Comment: actually the camera button its for rendering the a rendered image, and eye icon its for viewport rendering, i think the eye unchecked affects the other way of rendering too.

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid I tested it myself and I find turning off the eye won't make it disappear in final render process, but hidden in viewport rendering. So I think 
the switches of visibility of "viewport rendering" (after all it's in viewports) and "final render" (by pressing "Render" button) are separated as "the eye" and "the camera".

Answer (score 0):

If that is a viewport render then the eye has to be active.

And if you are using render layers and a viewport render make sure you have the door's layer selected and not just checked.

This can also apply to fully rendered layers if you are using Render nodes as well

checked layers will only show up in the full render where as the layer that is selected shows up in the viewport render

[when the eye is active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWMTB.png)

[image: When the eye is not active]

[image]

[image]